# Codeigniter error Message: Undefined variable: records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am a newbie in CI. I used MY_Controller.php as main controller. i'm trying to print pairs of data in my CodeIgniter view. However, I'm getting the following error. What I'm I doing wrong?

Error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Blockquote
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: records
>   Filename: views/country.php
>   Line Number: 21
>    Backtrace:
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\modules\Reference\views\country.php Line: 21 Function: _error_handler
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php Line: 362 Function: include
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php Line: 304 Function: _ci_load
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\modules\Template\views\v_admin_template.php Line: 370 Function: view
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php Line: 362 Function: include
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php Line: 304 Function: _ci_load
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\modules\Template\controllers\Template.php Line: 17 Function: view
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\application\modules\Reference\controllers\Reference.php Line: 21 Function: admin_template
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\db_student\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

My Controller

```
<?php
class C_country extends MY_Controller{

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('Crudcountry');
        $records = $this->Crudcountry->getRecords();    

        $this->load->view('country', ['records'=>$records]);
    }

    public function create(){
        $this->load->view('create_country');
    }
    public function save(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country_name', 'Country Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
        if( $this->form_validation->run() )
        {
            $data = $this->input->post();
            $this->load->model('Crudcountry');
            if( $this->Crudcountry->saveRecord( $data ) ){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Record Saved Successfully.');
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Record Failed to Save!');
            }
            return redirect('C_country');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('create_country');
        }
    }
    public function edit( $record_id ){
        $this->load->model('Crudcountry');
        $record = $this->Crudcountry->getAllRecords( $record_id );
        $this->load->view('update_country', ['record'=>$record]);
    }

    public function update( $record_id ){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country_name', 'Country Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
        if( $this->form_validation->run() )
        {
            $data = $this->input->post();
            $this->load->model('Crudcountry');
            if( $this->Crudcountry->updateRecords( $record_id, $data ) ){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Record Updated Successfully.');
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Failed to Update!');
            }
            return redirect('C_country');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('update');
        }
    }

    public function delete( $record_id ){

        $this->load->model('Crudcountry');
        if( $this->Crudcountry->deleteRecord( $record_id ) ){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Record Deleted Successfully.');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('response', 'Failed to Delete Record!.');
        }
        return redirect('C_country');
    }
}
?>
```

My Model

```
<?php
class Crudcountry extends CI_Model{

    public function getRecords(){
        $query = $this->db->get('refcountry');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function saveRecord( $data ){
        return $this->db->insert('refcountry', $data);
    }

    public function getAllRecords( $record_id ){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('refcountry', array('id_country' => $record_id));
        if( $query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row();
        }
    }

    public function updateRecords( $record_id, $data ){
        return $this->db->where('id_country', $record_id)
                ->update('refcountry', $data);
    }

    public function deleteRecord( $record_id ){
        return $this->db->delete('refcountry', array('id_country' => $record_id));
    }
}
?>
```

My View country.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <?php if( $error = $this->session->flashdata('response') ): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
        <?php echo $error; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?php echo anchor("Reference/C_country/create", 'Create', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Country Name</th>
              <th>Operations</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(count($records) ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $records as $record): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $record->country_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo anchor("C_country/edit/{$record->id_country}", 'Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo anchor("C_country/delete/{$record->id_country}", 'Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <tr>No Records Found!</tr>  
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

My View create_country.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="container">

    <?php echo form_open('Reference/C_country/save', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <div class="container"> </div>
        <legend>Create Country</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Country Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">

                        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'country_name', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Country Name', 'value'=>set_value('country_name')]); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php echo form_error('country_name'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">

            <?php echo form_submit(['value'=>'Submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
            <?php echo form_reset(['value'=>'Reset', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

My View update_country.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="container">

    <?php echo form_open("Reference/C_country/update/{$record->id_country}", ['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <div class="container"> </div>
        <legend>Create Country</legend>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Country Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">

                        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'country_name', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Country Name', 'value'=>set_value('country_name', $record->country_name)]); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php echo form_error('country_name'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>  


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">

            <?php echo form_submit(['value'=>'Submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
            <?php echo form_reset(['value'=>'Reset', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code so that the issue is still there. Throw away (comment out) differnt parts to track what exactly causes the issue: this is both a skill you'll need to develop anyway and this is also a way to increase chances that your question will be answered. Best regards

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. There is way too much posted code here. Try to narrow down the issue you are facing with smalled block of code.

Comment: Reduced BlockQuote size, removed unrelevant apache tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that the variable is not passed to the view.

here in the controller

```
$this->load->view('country', ['records'=>$records]);
```

are you sure there is something in $records?

```
$this->load->view('country', ['records'=>'foo']);
```

does this gives the same error?

Answer (score 0):

In your view file `(country.php)`,

change `(Line Number: 21)`

```
<?php if(count($records) ): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if( isset($records) && count($records) ): ?>
```

Comment: @HendrayanaFauzi welcome you may consider accept if solved

Comment: I'd rather use `<?php if( isset($records) && count($records) > 0 ): ?>` to avoid casting the result of `count()` (`int`) to an boolean, or remove it altogether as it will probably be greater than 0 as soon as the array is defined. That being said, if would probably be smarter to define `$records` as an empty array in the model and keep the `count()` logic only in the view.

Comment: @Capsule true, its better to define empty array in model itselft, to avoid error I used `isset()`, for example `php -r 'echo count($undefined_element);'` will throw same error that is `Undefined variable:`

Answer (score 0):

Try loading like

```
$this->load->model('Crudcountry');

$data['records'] = $this->Crudcountry->getAllRecords( $record_id );

$this->load->view('update_country', $data);
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Also when loading another view on to view instead of `include('header.php')` use

```
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to send data like this

```
    $record['records'] = $this->Crudcountry->getAllRecords( $record_ids);
    $this->load->view('update_country', $record);
```

And access data on view like this

```
 <?php foreach( $records as $record): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $record->country_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo anchor("C_country/edit/{$record->id_country}", 'Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo anchor("C_country/delete/{$record->id_country}", 'Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```